# In Vim, How to substitute within a subexpression?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I want to prepend all my classNames with `o-` without having to adjust every className by hand. I use Vim.

I know a substitution will do the job so I came up with this, which is obviously not working (and the reason I am here).

```
:%s/class="[^"]*"/\='class="'.substitute(submatch(0), '[^o-]*', 'o-'.submatch(1), 'g').'"'/g
```

Explanation:

1. `class="[^"]` - matches all instances of `class="foo bar baz"`
2. `\='class="'.substitute(subexp).'"'` - replaces the found instances `class="subexp"`
3. `subexp` in two should repace each space separated class with the original className prepended with `o-`

All in all, in procedural terms, for each `class="foo bar baz"`, replace each className with the className prepended with `o-`.

Thanks in advance.

**(BONUS) EDIT**: How can this be written to ignore or cope with classNames that already begin with `o-`, when encountered, so that `o-o-` is **not** a resulting edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the example

```
class="foo bar baz"
```

This line works:

```
%s/class="\zs[^"]*\ze"/\=join( map(split(submatch(0)),"'o-'.v:val"), ' ')/
```

So there are nested function calls:

- I didn't use `\<` boundary because in case some "special" char in your classname, it will fail. E.g. `# - or @`. I don't know if it is the case in your language.
- submatch(0) is the `"foo bar baz"`
- `split()` makes it(each class) into list
- `map()` add `o-` to each classname
- `join()` turns the modified list back to string

So after executing this command, you should see:

```
class="o-foo o-bar o-baz"
```

#### Edit for the "Bonus" requirement:

We just need check each element(classname). Check the codes below, it should work for you:

```
%s/class="\zs[^"]*/\=join(map(split(submatch(0)),"(v:val=~'^o-'?'':'o-').v:val"))/
```

here we have:

```
(v:val=~'^o-'?'':'o-').v:val
```

If the element starts with `o-` then we don't add another `o-` any more.

Comment: You can drop the last `' '` from `join()`, the separator is a single space by default.

Comment: @SatoKatsura you are right, I wrote `, ` at very beginning, then found it should be space, simply removed comma.. :)

Comment: @Kent - Where is the handy reference for allowable function calls for use in these situations? I'm fine with a `man` command or any online resource.

Comment: @toszter in vim do `:h functionname(` you will see.

Comment: @Kent - Can you comment to my **(BONUS) EDIT**?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to take advantage of `\zs...\ze`, and the fact that `submatch(0)` resolves to the string matched between `\zs...\ze`:

```
:%s/\mclass="\zs.\{-}\ze"/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\<', 'o-', 'g')/g
```

If you don't want to rely on that you can still use explicit grouping:

```
:%s/\mclass="\zs\([^"]*\)\ze"/\=substitute(submatch(1), '\<', 'o-', 'g')/g
```

Comment: I don't think the second example is ever worth using since its more characters for the same thing as the first.

Comment: @FDinoff The fact that `submatch(0)` expands to the string matched between `\zs...\ze` is undocumented.  It makes sense, but it arguably isn't what most people would expect of it.  It hasn't changed in a while, but there is a remote possibility that Bram eventually sees it as a bug and fixes it. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura - Can you comment to my **(BONUS) EDIT**?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Maybe not explicitly but submatch(0) returns the matched text. `\zs` set the start of the match and `\ze` set the end of the match. So my reading of it makes it seem like the parts between `\zs` and `\ze` would appear in `submatch(0)`. What do you think people would expect?

Comment: @FDinoff That's wrong, `\zs` and `\ze` have no effect on what is _matched_, they only take effect on what is _replaced_ (which is why they are so much more useful than lookaheads and lookbehinds).  Consequently, the conceptually consistent behaviour for `submatch(0)` would be to return the entire string matched, regardless of `\zs` and `\ze`.  But I agree that the current behaviour is more useful in practice.

Comment: @toszter Use negative lookahead.  And consider not changing the rules of the game while playing, thank you.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Are we reading different documentation? (Taken from `:help pattern.txt`) https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/089af18d1fd0961ff504ee72db0156bbfe509cdf/runtime/doc/pattern.txt#L471 and this https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/089af18d1fd0961ff504ee72db0156bbfe509cdf/runtime/doc/pattern.txt#L825 clearly say they set the start and end of the match.

Comment: @FDinoff The docs should add "for the purpose of replacement", or something to that effect.  As I said, `\zs` and `\ze` don't change what is matched, they only affect what is replaced.  Can you give an example that disproves this?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Maybe I don't understand what you mean by match then. But I think according to you `echo matchstr('hello world', 'hello world')` and `echo matchstr('hello world', 'hel\zslo wor\zeld')` would return the same string. Since `matchstr()` returns the matched string. (The two expressions don't print the same thing.) Can I get an explanation of what you consider a match?

Comment: @FDinoff "Match" = a boolean value, the (negated) result of `regexec()` in C, or `$str =~ m/pat/` in Perl, or `re.search(pat, str) is not None` in Pyton, or `str =~ pat` in Vim.  "What is matched" = a string, the result of `pmatch[0]` in C, or `$&` (or `$MATCH`) in Perl, or `re.search(pat, str).group(0)` in Python, or `\0` in sed, or `matchstr(str, pat)` in Vim... but only if there are no `\zs` and `\ze` involved.  There is no way to get the exact equivalent of `\0` in Vim when you have `\zs` and `\ze`, which hopefully explains my point.  As usual Vim is trying to do too many things at once.